# Hyphen Handling Apache Velocity 2.1 - Is this a Bug?

Tags: java, templates, velocity

I have raised this issue in the Apache Velocity Mailing List but I have not received a response so I am reposting it here...

I am using the newly released Apache Velocity 2.1 and I am testing the hyphen as identifier name but I am hitting a bug or something?  I have set the property Velocity.PARSER_HYPHEN_ALLOWED but it is only allowed on single data not on map or collection data.

I have this template:

```
hello-world.properties.vm 
---------------------------------------------------------- 
Slash: ${sample-slash}
Slash in a Map: ${map.sample-slash}
```

---

And I have this sample test case:

```
public class ApacheVelocityTest {
    private final String RESOURCES_DIR = "src/test/resources";

    @Test
    public void testVelocity() {
        Path templatePath = Paths.get(RESOURCES_DIR, "templates", "hello-world.properties.vm");


        VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
        ve.setProperty(Velocity.PARSER_HYPHEN_ALLOWED, true);

        ve.init();
        Template t = ve.getTemplate(templatePath.toString());

        VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();

        context.put("sample-slash", "SLASH");

        Map<String, String> sampleData = createData();
        context.put("map", sampleData);

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        t.merge(context, writer);

        System.out.println(writer.toString());
    }

    public Map<String, String> createData() {
        Map<String, String> mapData = new HashMap<String, String>();

        mapData.put("sample-slash", "USER1");

        return mapData;

    }
}
```

Now, the first "sample-slash" is rendered correctly but the one that is in the java map is not..it is throwing out an error like this:

---

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "-slash}" at src\test\resources\templates\hello-world.properties.vm[line 5, column 22]
Was expecting one of:
    "[" ...
    "|" ...
    "}" ...
    "}" ...

    at org.apache.velocity.Template.process(Template.java:154)
```

The parser exception is being thrown by the object that is embedded into the java map.

Do I have any workaround for this developers?  Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You **did** receive an answer on the mailing list a few hours later :-)

Comment: Thank you for creating the issue, by the way.

Comment: That is probably because the dot notation is primarily for properties and there (in Java fields and methods) hyphens are forbidden. To access a map you should call `$map["sample-slash"]` http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.1/user-guide.html#properties and http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.1/user-guide.html#index-notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug with the `parser.allow_hyphen_in_identifiers` backward compatibility mode in version 2.1.

You can workaround it with:

```
$map.get("sample-slash")
```

or

```
$map["sample-slash"]
```

The bug is fixed in the main development branch.